# Pythonic way to access Flask request arguements

Tags: python, flask

In my Flask app I am setting a number of local variables that have come in via an API call, using the

```
from flask import request
.
.
submission_id = request.args.get('submission_id')
grader = request.args.get('grader')
grading_factor = float(request.args.get('grading_factor'))
answer_key = request.args.get('answer_key')
submission_key = request.args.get('submission_key')
```

What is a less repetitive or otherwise more Pythonic way of setting these 5 variables?

Comment: Do you need them as separate variables?

Comment: I'd assign `request.args.get` to some `getarg` variable to get rid of the redundancy, but other than that this seems optimal. If you want something fancier and have many endpoints and plenty of time, you might write a decorator that maps request args to the view function arguments.

Comment: @bereal that sounds interesting ... are there any resources you can point me to for mapping request args to view function args?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, you could come up with a decorator that would map the request arguments to the corresponding function parameters, such as:

```
def map_args(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        all_args = dict(request.args, **kwargs)
        return func(**all_args)

    return wrapper
```

Then:

```
@app.route('/mypath')
@map_args
def handler(submission_id, grader, grading_factor, ...):
    """the remaining logic"""
```

That's similar to what Flask does with the [view_args](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L1605), except that it does not do any type conversions, which this margin is too narrow to contain.

Answer (score 2):

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

class DotDict(object):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self._inner = inner

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self._inner.get(item)

    def get(self, item, default=None):
        return self._inner.get(item, default)

class LazyAttribute(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, attr):
        self.obj = obj
        self.attr = attr

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return getattr(getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, 'obj'),
                               object.__getattribute__(self, 'attr')),
                       item)

rargs = DotDict(LazyAttribute(request, 'args'))

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    print rargs.a, rargs.c, rargs.get('d', 3)
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Accessing http://localhost:5000/?a=1 prints `1 None 3` in the terminal.

The `LazyAttribute` class is because calling just `DotDict(request.args)` outside of a request context throws an error. The alternative is to make a function:

```
def rargs():
    return DotDict(request.args)
```

but I wanted to make usage as smooth as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think there's anything wrong with the way you're doing it. But, there are a couple of different approaches you could take; the first being to the call to get the argument from `request`:

```
from flask import request

# ...

def getRequestArg(name, *args):
    return request.args.get(name, *args)

submission_id = getRequestArg('submission_id')
grader = getRequestArg('grader')
grading_factor = float(getRequestArg('grading_factor'))
answer_key = getRequestArg('answer_key')
submission_key = getRequestArg('submission_key')
```

If you don't need each of these to be separate local variables, you could store them all in a `dict`:

```
from flask import request

# ...

args = {}
arg_names = ('submission_id', 'grader', 'grading_factor', 'answer_key', 'submission_key')
for arg in arg_names:
    args[arg] = request.args.get(arg)
```